# How to chain multiple redux thunk asyn call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I have a function called fetchStudentId as below:-

```
export function fetchStudentId(studentJoiningId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

const state = getState()
blah
blah
blah

const student_data = {my required data ..., studentJoiningId}

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(student_data),
  mode: "cors",
}

return fetch("fvfcfgcfcfgc.fcfgcfc/yfcfcgcfg/hffgcfgccg", options)
  .then((json) => {
    dispatch(randomFunction(json))
    dispatch(fetchSudentDetails(json.student_id)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
  })
  }
}
```

below is my fetchSudentDetails function in which i am checking the name present in the response is "NONE" or somethingelse.

I will be calling fetchSudentDetails again and again untill response is not "NONE"

```
export function fetchSudentDetails(student_id) {

  return (dispatch, getState) => { 
const state = getState()
let fetching = state.fetching

if (fetching) {

  return 
  fetch("xdxfxdfx.com/jvhjv/jbjb")
    .then((json) => {
      switch (json.details.name) {
        case "NONE":
          setTimeout(
            () => dispatch(fetchSudentDetails(student_id)),
            FETCH_OFFER_DELAY
          )
          break
        default: // SUCCESS
          dispatch(setstudentdetails(json.details.complete))
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    })
}
  }
}
```

So, everything is working fine as of now if I call `this.props.fetchStudentJoiningId("jkjnkjnkjnnjkn")` for one student

Now, I want to fetch 10 student's details simultaneously i.e
I need to call 
    fetchStudentJoiningId("jbjhb"),
     fetchStudentJoiningId("khbhjbjh"),
    ....(similar 10 calls ) 
and once all the 10 calls are succeeded then only I need to have my logic

So, far What I have tried

```
export function fetchTenStudents(dispatch) {
  return Promise
  .all([dispatch(fetchStudentId("kjhhjbhjb")),
    dispatch(fetchStudentId("vghvg")),
    dispatch(fetchStudentId("kjhhjbgvghvhjb")),
   ...(10 calls)
  ])
  .then(([xx, yy, zz, aa, oo, pp, rr, ss, tt, gvgh]) => {

  })
}
```

But its throwing the following error:-
    Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

While looking into this, I found that recalling the function fetchSudentDetails() is causing this issue

I want to call 10 fetchStudentId() simultaneously. Upon successful completion of all the 10 calls, I need to have my logic.

Successful completion of each request means fetchStudentId will be called and we will get student id and using that studentid I need to call fetchStudentDetails and fetchStudentDetails will be calling itself until name is not "NONE". Once the name is not "NONE", the request is succeeded.

I need to wait for 10 successful completion. I can't change the behaviour of fetchStudentDetails calling again and again.

I am open to make use of redux-saga.

Comment: Try using some kind of middleware such as: [redux-sequence-action](https://github.com/jasonslyvia/redux-sequence-action)

Comment: Went trough the github doc,  I have already tried that using Promise.all. Its not working as I need to recall fetchStudentDetails again and again and  redux-sequence-action only provides syntax sugar. its not handling the recalling scenario. Let me know if I am missing somthing